# can anyone tell me how to create a directory in freenas /mnt/test for example

Tags: directory, truenas

can anyone tell me how to create a directory in freenas /mnt/test for example

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir /mnt/test
```

If this is not what you were looking for, then please expand and rephrase your question.

Comment: A terse slapdown, but it made me laugh!  Etienne, we need to know a **lot** more about what you've got, what you want to do with it, what you've done so far, and how it worked or failed.

Answer (score 0):

You need do a few things before the disks are accessible:

Add the disks, then format them.  Add a mount point - just 'test' in your case. This is followed by the enabling of SMB/CIFS then the creation of a share.

It will then be accessible from //ip.address/test